# vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack-simple: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I just started  with Vue today and got stuck.

Following is the summary:

```
    npm install -g vue-cli  [Result - Successful]

    vue init webpack-simple C:\vue [Result - Unsuccessful]
    vue init webpack-simple ./    [Result - Unsuccessful]
```

**Throws following error:**

```
    vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack-simple: tunneling socket could
    not be established, statusCode=403
```

**Then tried the following commands:**

```
   npm config set http-profix null
   vue init webpack-simple ./
```

It still throws the error.

Any pointers to this. I am running the script behind proxy wall.

Thanks.

Comment: By default its set to "Allow VPN over metered networks" option to "on" and "allow vpn while roaming" to "on".

Comment: As its at office, am using the connection behind proxy walls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, I suspect is that you're installing from behind a VPN.

### You can try disabling it to do the install

on corporate networks that's not always the option

### If you don't have the option to disable...

you may be able to use
  `npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/`

The reason that works is that you're no longer connecting to the *default* which uses `https`, where the SSL is failing due the the proxy.

Note that there is an issue of security if you opt to use `http` instead of `https`

### You may also be able to use a proxy definition in a `.npmrc` file

If you have your proxy information, you can add it to the `.npmrc` file in the directory.

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#https-proxy

```
proxy http://{proxy_server}:{proxy_port}
https-proxy http://{proxy_server}:{proxy_port}
strict-ssl=false
```

[src gist](https://gist.github.com/ikaruce/aaaf884a1f48555b5d5f)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel! Finally, it worked by making changes to the .npmrc directory.